# How to sort NSMutableArray Values Aa-Zz in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, sorting, nsmutablearray

I am trying to sort the NSMutablArray values by Aa-Zz format in iPhone app. I have used the below code in my project.

```
for (id key in [dictionary allKeys])
        {
            id value = [dictionary valueForKey:key];
            [duplicateArray addObject:value];
            [value release];
            value =nil;
            NSSortDescriptor *sortdis = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Name" ascending:YES] autorelease];
            NSArray *discriptor = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortdis,nil];
            mutableArray = [[duplicateArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:discriptor]retain];
        }   
        NSLog(@"mutableArray : %@", mutableArray);
[mutableArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

The app getting crash with this error log: `[__NSArrayI sortUsingSelector:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.`

But, i have searched and found the reason for the crash. My mutableArray values are like this,

```
(
        {
        Id = 00001;
        Name = "ABCD";
    },
        {
        Id = 00002;
        Name = "BCDE";
    },
        {
        Id = 00003;
        Name = "ZXYS";
    },
        {
        Id = 00004;
        Name = "abcd";
    },
        {
        Id = 00009;
        Name = "bcde";
    },
)
```

I want to sort this array valuse like **ABCD, abcd, BCDE, bcde, ZXYs**.
Can anyone please help to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gopinath. Please use this updated code in your project.

```
    for (id key in [dictionary allKeys])
    {
        id value = [dictionary valueForKey:key];
        [duplicateArray addObject:value];
        [value release];
        value =nil;
        NSSortDescriptor *sortdis = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]autorelease];
        NSArray *discriptor = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortdis,nil];
        mutableArray = [[duplicateArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:discriptor]retain];
    }   
    NSLog(@"mutableArray : %@", mutableArray);
```

I hope it will help you. Thanks.

Comment: This helps, but its not good code. You should only sort the array once, after you are done adding everything to it! Move all the code that sorts outside the loop. Also the value does not need to be released - you did not create it. So lose the release line.

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (id key in [dictionary allKeys])
    {
        id value = [dictionary valueForKey:key];
        [duplicateArray addObject:value];
    }   
    NSSortDescriptor *sortdis = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]autorelease];
    NSArray *discriptor = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortdis,nil];
    NSArray* notAMutableArray = [[duplicateArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:discriptor]retain];
    NSLog(@"notAMutableArray : %@", notAMutableArray);
```

I did not run this, but its a better start...